# Distinguish between hidden and active buffers in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to distinguish between hidden and active buffers in Vim?

I need to determine if a buffer is active in a window so I can toggle it.
Tried `bufloaded`, `bufexists` and `buflisted` but they all return 1 for both active and hidden buffers.

(I have `set hidden` and `set bufhidden=hide` in my vimrc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `bufwinnr()` to check if a buffer is open in a window.  The result is `-1` if it is not.

Comment: This doesn't work, you want `empty(win_findbuf(n))` to check if a buffer is hidden. The buffer might be active in a window in another tab.

Answer (score 4):

You can use :ls to see a list of all buffers.
Buffers with a 'h' next to the buffer number are hidden. 'a' indicates active buffer.